# After setting up docker image, site does not load with localhost:port

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Hi I am setting up one docker image available on -https://github.com/10up/wp-local-docker

I have changed all the ports mentioned both .yml files -
- docker-compose.yml
- admin-compose.yml

Than I have done setup as mentioned in documentation on page.

My issue is I have already installed Apache 2 on my local on port 80 and I have setup docker nginx image on port 8088. After setup when I run the localhost:8088 it shows error "Secure Connection Failed" does not show default nginx page.

only thing I changed in .yml file is port which I want to expose all the images.

Any idea where I am doing wrong or miss any thing ? Below is my .yml files-

-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated"
    ports:
      - "3336:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  mailcatcher:
     image: schickling/mailcatcher
     ports:
       - "1025:1025"
       - "1080:1080"
     environment:
       MAILCATCHER_PORT: 1025
  memcached:
    image: memcached:latest
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.5
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms750m -Xmx750m"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - "./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:cached"
      - "./config/elasticsearch/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins:cached"
      - "./data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:delegated"
  phpfpm:
    image: 10up/phpfpm
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - memcached
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - "./wordpress:/var/www/html:cached"
      - "./config/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:cached"
      - "./config/php-fpm/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:cached"
      - "./config/php-fpm/wp-cli.local.yml:/var/www/html/wp-cli.local.yml:cached"
      - "~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached"
    extra_hosts:
      - "docker-local.localhost:172.18.0.1"
    nginx:
    depends_on:
      - phpfpm
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
      - "4443:443"
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - "./wordpress:/var/www/html:cached"
      - "./config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:cached"
      - "./config/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:cached"
      - "./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx:cached"
  wpsnapshots:
    image: 10up/wpsnapshots
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - phpfpm
    volumes:
      - "./config/wpsnapshots:/home/wpsnapshots/.wpsnapshots:cached"
      - "./wordpress:/var/www/html:cached"
```

-admin-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST mysql
    links:
      - mysql:db
    ports:
      - 8892:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  phpmemcacheadmin:
    image: hitwe/phpmemcachedadmin
    ports:
      - "8893:80"
    depends_on:
      - memcached
```

Comment: if possible post your yml files

Comment: @SriniM Added .yml files

Comment: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/288

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]: do you need _all_ of these containers, with _all_ of these options, to reproduce the issue?  Which specific container is producing the problem?  What's the actual text of the error message you're getting?  Do you need extra artifacts (like an nginx configuration) to demonstrate this?